# what's the best way to have a list with multilingual content

Tags: list, language, localization

Good day, SharePointers
a customer requirement is to have CVs entered in a list with his name in English and a local language.
which means we will have a field for each language.

is there a better way to accomplish that in SP 2010?

thanks

Comment: what do you mean, "a field for each language". why don't you want to use only two fields: for english & for local language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not limit it to the following columns?

1. Name (English)
2. Name (Local)
3. Local Language

Comment: Jaap is back :-D

Comment: it has so many other columns including lookup and description.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you meant though

Comment: Will you ever store more than 2 names against one item? If not, why would you need a column for each language? You could have an optional third column to indicate which language the non-English version of name was in. Obviously your other columns would be added to the list as well, I am just listing the ones you would need to allow for multilingual names.

Comment: no, only two languages

Comment: but I'm asking if there's a different official way to do that

Comment: No official way. What I am proposing gets around having a column per language, does it not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a column for every language, unless it is limited to only a few as you will run out of available columns eventually.

Other options include:

- One field that stores all the other non-primary language names
- Create a second list with: Name, Localized Name and Locale columns.  Make the Name column at look up to your primary list & Locale could be a choice field with the various locales in it.  Enter a row for each localized name for that person.  A typical One to Many DB relationship.  A stretch goal could be to customize the primary List View to show the related name rows inline.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create another list for CV information. That list should columns: linking id, language(valuelist) and CV-text. By that way there you could have as many languages as you want.